# string of letters only , without any special character

Tags: c++, c++14

i wanted to take input of letters only but its not working properly.
if i input a random string like abcd123
it repeats try again when i enter again same abcd123
it will output ignoring the condition
i want this only to take abcd.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool IsLetters(string &input)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
 {   
     int uppercaseChar = toupper(input[i]); //condition for letters
     if (uppercaseChar < 'A' || uppercaseChar > 'Z') 
     {   cout<<"try again\n";
        cin>>input;
         return IsLetters;
     }
 }

 return true; 
}


int main() 
{
 string x;
 cout<<"enter your name\n";
 cin>>x; //string input
 if (IsLetters(x)) // function call
 {
     cout << "your name is\n"<<x;
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (std::any_of(input.begin(), input.end(), [](char ch) { return std::isalpha(ch); }); ) { try_again; }`  -- That is a one line implementation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change logic, pls try following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    bool IsLetters(string& input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            int uppercaseChar = toupper(input[i]); //condition for letters
            if (uppercaseChar < 'A' || uppercaseChar > 'Z')
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        string x;
        cout << "enter your name\n";
        cin >> x; //string input
    
        while (IsLetters(x)) // function call
        {
            cout << "try again\n";
            cin >> x;
        }
        cout << "your name is\n" << x;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The correct function to use is [std::isupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and not comparing with `A` and `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this straightforward solution.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        string s;
        cout <<"enter your name\n";
        cin >> s;
        int flag = false;
    
        while (flag != true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
            {
                if (!(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') &&  !(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'))
                {
                    flag  = true;
                    break;
                }
            } 
    
            if (flag == true)
            {
                cout<<"try again\n";
                flag  = false;
                cin >> s;
            } else {
                cout << s;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The correct function to use is [std::isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha), and not comparing with `A` and `Z`.

Comment: thanks for letting me know of this function. I did not aware of this. been doing it like this

Comment: The program you have only works for English letters, and on an ASCII-based system.  That may work for a majority of the computers out there running as English systems, but it will not work for non-ASCII systems that do not have the letters in contiguous sequences, such as EBCDIC.  It will also not fully work for non-English, ASCII systems, since the alphabet of another language may have more lower/upper case characters and alphabetic characters.  The `std::isalpha` knows exactly what system is being used, and returns the correct result.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. you are right. we don't usually think of this cases in the first place. thanks.

Comment: Yes, for example, Spanish has the tilde n, both upper and lower case.  That doesn't exist in English.